# Implement Child Delegate in Parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to implement Child's delegates in Parent?

**Parent.h:**

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
```

**Child.h**

```
#import "Parent.h"
@protocol ChildDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)someMethod;
@end

@interface Child : Parent
```

I cannot declare Parent's interface to be:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject<ChildDelegate>
```

since it need to import `"Child.h"` and it will be circular import.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Move `ChildDelegate` into a new header file, say `"ChildDelegate.h"`.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Is it a separated file and that file must be imported by both parent and child?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare protocol conformance in source files (with `.m` extension).

You can declare `Parent` class in `Parent.h` without conformance to `ChildDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
```

And in your `Parent.m` file you can write something as following.

```
#import "Child.h"

@interface Parent() <ChildDelegate>

@end

@implementation Parent
// Your implementation code here
@end
```